# How to get dropdownlistFor selected value in controller in form of string in MVC

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59J3a.png)

Instead of "A+" i need that value which is selected by user from dropdown list.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that you have ModelView Class like below:

```
Public Class Test
{
    public int SelectedBloodGroup { get; set; }

    public IList<SelectListItem> AvailableBloodGroups { get; set; }
}
```

Then You Should Fill `AvailableBloodGroups` in your model in HttpGet of your Controller.

So you should have this in your **View**:

```
 <div class="col-md-8">
    <select asp-for="SelectedBloodGroup" asp-items="Model.AvailableBloodGroups">"AvailableBloodGroups"</select>
 </div>
```

Then with Http Post post your form to your controller and `SelectedBloodGroup` is then value that User Select it.

use this also in your string to use value

```
$"where bloodGroup = {model.SelectedBloodGroup}"
```

Check this Links For More:
[mvc6-select-tag-helper](https://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2015/05/18/mvc6-select-tag-helper.aspx)

Or
[asp-net-core-custom-drop-down-list](https://medium.com/@dmitrysikorsky/asp-net-core-custom-drop-down-list-86bcd60f2cf2)

Or
[MicroSoft-how-make-a-aspfor-dropdown-list](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0401ce05-1ecf-40b7-a598-33692169ad7a/how-make-a-aspfor-dropdown-list?forum=aspdotnetcore)